# Проблема с groovy

Tags: java

```
String scriptText = "int a = 12;";

ImportCustomizer ic = new ImportCustomizer();
ic.addImports("my.package.MyClass");

CompilerConfiguration cc = new CompilerConfiguration();
cc.addCompilationCustomizers(ic);

Binding gb = new Binding();
gb.setVariable("myObject", myObject);

GroovyShell gsh = new GroovyShell(gb, cc);

gsh.evaluate(scriptText);

Object res = gsh.evaluate(scriptText);
```

Среда разработки говорит, что строчка

```
gb.setVariable("myObject", myObject);
```

является ошибкой. Как исправить?

Comment: А какую ошибку он говорит вы нам не скажите из принципа?

Comment: Он подчеркивает эту строчку красным и при компиляции говорит Error:(86, 36) error: cannot find symbol variable myObject

Comment: Ну. В гугл транслейт если вбить - то что выдаст? ....... у вас переменная с  именем `myObject ` где?

Comment: В документации говориться что она не требуется в объявлении: При таком биндинге в скрипте не должно быть никакого объявления переменной myObject: ни def myObject, ни MyClass myObject. Она уже как бы объявлена, просто сразу используйте её: myObject.method(); myObject.prop = ...

Comment: В какой документации? Покажите ссылку.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`myObect` не должен объявляться в скрипте, который хотите запустить, в котором хотите использовать этот `myObect`, но в самой-то программе он должен быть!

Java

```
 MyClass myObject = new MyClass();
 ...
 gb.setVariable("myObject", myObject);
 ...
```

Скрипт Groovy

```
 ...
 myObject.method()
 myObject.prop = 123     // Все эти действия над объектом,
 println(myObject.prop)  // переданном скрипту через binding
 ...
```

В скрипте можно задействовать какие-нибудь переменные и если одна из них будет def myObject, то он перекроет объект не будет виден скрипту, а будет видна собственная переменная.

Скрипт Groovy

```
 ...
 def myObject // это скроет от скрипта binding "myObject"
 ...
 myObject.method()
 myObject.prop = 123    // Все эти действия уже над переменной myObject, 
 println(myObject.prop) // определённой в скрипте, а не переданной ему в binding
 ...
```